# Is there an efficient way/function to handle combinations of nulls in an equation in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have a column `total` in my table, which is built upon an equation `total = w - (x + y + z)` where `w, x, y` , and `z` are all columns as well, and they are all from different tables I'm left joining. There are cases where x is null, y is null, or z is null. There are also cases in which `x` and `y` are null, `y` and `z` are null, and so on until covering all possible combinations of nulls in the equation.

Currently, I'm handling this by using a `CASE` clause and a *lot* of `WHEN`s. Here's an example snippet:

```
WHEN (x IS NOT NULL) 
     AND (y IS NOT NULL)
     AND (z IS NOT NULL) THEN (w - (x + y + z))
WHEN (x IS NOT NULL)
     AND (y IS NOT NULL)
     AND (z IS NULL) THEN (w - (x + y))
WHEN (x IS NOT NULL)
     AND (y IS NULL)
     AND (z IS NOT NULL) THEN (w - (x + z))
...
```

My problem is that I am working with more than 4 columns, resulting in a pretty large number of these combinations. While I could just write out all the combinations with a bunch of `WHEN`s (this is what I've been doing), it takes a really long time and I'd love to know if there's a more efficient way of accomplishing the task, perhaps a function I could write.

Answer (score 4):

Yes!  You can use the COALESCE function

```
select
  (w - (coalesce(x,0) + coalesce(y,0) + coalesce(z,0))) as Total
from tbl
```

COALESCE will return the first non-null value in the list.  So in the above case, if x,y or z are null, zero will be returned in their place.